# Click on asp:button inside modal popup doesn't work on Win7 x64 platform

Tags: asp.net

I am developing ASP.NET application and I have a modal popup dialog with asp:button on it. I was developing my application on Windows 7 x86 platform, and there, click on this button works fine. But when I deploy the exact same code on Windows 7 x64 platform, click on this button inside modal popup doesn't work. Does anybody have idea what am I missing?

This is the Panel that I am showing and ModalPopupExtender that I use to show it.

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="Extender_ConfirmChange" 
    PopupControlID="Panel_ConfirmChange" 
    TargetControlID="HiddenFieldChange" 
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" 
    Drag="True" 
    PopupDragHandleControlID="LegendChange" 
    OkControlID="BtnYes_ConfirmChange" 
    CancelControlID="BtnNo_ConfirmChange" 
    DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldChange" runat="server" />

<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel_ConfirmChange" Height="100px" Width="400px"      style="display: none">

    <div id="Div1" runat="server" class="UserData">

        <fieldset class='UserPanel'>

            <legend id="LegendChange" class="CursorCorrector">
                <asp:Label ID="LabelChange" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="ChangeResource"></asp:Label>
            </legend>                    

            <asp:Panel runat="server" BackColor="White" >

                <asp:Table runat="server">
                    <asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:Image ID="img" ImageUrl="../Images/Shield_Yellow32.png" runat="server" 
                                meta:resourcekey="imageChangeResource" style="padding-right:8px"/>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblChange" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lblChangeResource" ></asp:Label>    
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                </asp:Table>

                <br />
                <br />

                <div class="button">
                    <asp:Button ID="BtnYes_ConfirmChange" runat="server" 
                        OnClick="BtnYes_ConfirmChange_OnClientClick" UseSubmitBehavior="False" 
                        Width="70px" meta:resourcekey="BtnYes_ConfirmChangeResource"/>
                    <asp:Button ID="BtnNo_ConfirmChange" runat="server" Width="70px" 
                        OnClick="BtnNo_ConfirmChange_OnClientClick" 
                        meta:resourcekey="BtnNo_ConfirmChangeResource"/>
                    <asp:Button ID="BtnCancel_ConfirmChange" runat="server" Width="70px" 
                        OnClick="BtnCancel_ConfirmChange_OnClientClick" 
                        meta:resourcekey="BtnCancel_ConfirmChangeResource"/>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>

        </fieldset>

    </div>

</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Showing some code will be helpful.